# How to plot Images on a chart?

Tags: jquery, html, css, charts

Using chart plugins like ChartJs or JqPlot its easy to create chart just by passing data into them ,but how to display Images instead of simple points on a chart.
After some research I found that one way to do this could be using images as background .How exactly to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need a low-level charting library that lets you interact with its underlying drawing surface (i.e. the SVG or canvas element) to not draw circles but images instead.

You could probably achieve that with [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)